# What PPAs support the ARM architecture (armel)?

Tags: 11.10, repository, arm

I'm running Ubuntu arm 11.10 on my asus eee pad tablet. I would like to have access to all my options.

What PPAs support armel right now?
Or
What third party repos work with ubuntu arm?

I usually like to add webupd8 etc... for x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is, unforunately, NONE.**

- This is because Launchpad currently [only supports the i386/amd64 architectures for PPA packages.](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA#Supported_architectures)
- armel packages *can* be [built after setting a special flag](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad-buildd/+bug/379592) to use a non-virtualized build environment, but because of security reasons this access is restricted to the core Ubuntu teams.

That's not to say there may not be third-party repositories offering armel versions, but there are no PPAs, per se.

Comment: know of any third party repos by any chance?

Comment: No. It seems you may just have to cross-compile on a PC, or leave it running overnight on the eeePad. The latter is actually fairly easy to do for any given PPA package.

Comment: they should really make use of scaleway for builds... or something.

Answer (score 1):

### launchpad PPA support for armel

According to this [launchpad answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/178715)...

> There are no current plans to make armel generally available but
> that's not to say it will not happen at some point.

It goes onto say...

> There are plans, but no concrete timeline. It's a difficult problem
> due to the lack of a secure, performant virtualisation solution for
> ARM devices.

There is a [blueprint available](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/other-arm-n-public-panda-ppa-build-cluster) - but from the above - no timeframe to implement it as yet.